# What's the order of response.history?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Let's suppose I have sent an HTTP request to A which redirected to B then C.

```
response = requests.get(A_url, allow_redirects = True)
```

From what I understand the contents of **response** are A.

But what's the order inside response.history? is it [B,C] or [C,B]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`requests` source code](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/99b3b492418d0751ca960178d274f89805095e4c/requests/sessions.py#L148), which uses `hist.append(resp)`, it looks to be ordered "ascending" (sequentially) in the order seen. So, `[A, B]` from your example.

```py
        hist = []  # keep track of history

        url = self.get_redirect_target(resp)
        previous_fragment = urlparse(req.url).fragment
        while url:
            prepared_request = req.copy()

            # Update history and keep track of redirects.
            # resp.history must ignore the original request in this loop
            hist.append(resp)
            resp.history = hist[1:]

            ...
```

This is a block of code from `.resolve_redirects()` which keeps looking for redirects until it is no longer redirected. `. get_redirect_target()`, in turn, while stop returning a URL (it will return `None`) if there is no redirect target, ending the `while url` loop seen above.

---

##### A Reproducible Example

Create the following Flask app:

```py
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/a")
def a():
    return redirect(url_for('b'))

@app.route("/b")
def b():
    return redirect(url_for('c'))

@app.route("/c")
def c():
    return "<p>Hello, C!</p>"
```

Serve it:

```sh
$ python3 -m flask run
```

Now send a request:

```py
>>> import requests
>>> resp = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/a")
>>> resp.history
[<Response [302]>, <Response [302]>]
>>> [x.url for x in resp.history]
['http://127.0.0.1:5000/a', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/b']
>>> resp.url
'http://127.0.0.1:5000/c'
```

Comment: and A in response right?

Comment: Sorry, fixed an inaccuracy in my original response. The `resp.history` will be `[A, B]` in this case. The `response.url` itself is the final destination, C.

Comment: Not correct... first destination is in response.url...